# MBP major virus I think

Tags: safari

I am sure I have got some virus(s) in my Mac book & I have no idea what to do about it. I download torrents on a regular basis. When I am in Safari, every time I click a link of any kind a new, extra tab opens that has nothing to do with what I have clicked. Usually it opens to mackepper or similar type "junk sale" web site.

Help!

Comment: Please provide screenshots, and did you reset your Safari settings already? If not, try it first.

Comment: I don't see why it should be unclear what he's asking. It might be a good idea to refurbish it a bit, but looks legit though.

Comment: i think this is more malware than virus, check your safari for plugins, extensions, home pages, used search engines and 'information bars'. and don't install mackeeper, it's malware in person.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you're experiencing MacKeeper and similar website ads.

What worked for me is a Safari extension called *AdBlock Plus*.

[Click this text to install AdBlock Plus for Safari.](https://data.getadblock.com/safari/AdBlock.safariextz)

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to check for both malware/viruses and adware:

For malware, grab ClamXav from:

http://www.clamxav.com/

For adware, grab AdwareMedic from:

http://www.adwaremedic.com/